# Spring MVC Rest - multiple parameters at URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have "transit manager" application. It's a simply app to test how to use Spring framework. I've created endpoint for adding new transit to database (Spring Data) and it works fine. I have added a few transits and now I want to get daily report and here I have problems. This is how endpoint should looks like:

`GET http://example.com/reports/daily?start_date=YYYY-MM-DD&end_date=YYYY-MM_DD`

And response(in JSON) for example:

```
{
  "total_distance": "90",
  "total_price":      "115"
}
```

What I suppose to do? Should I add new fields "startDate" and "endDate" in model class?

This is how my model class looks:

```
@Entity
public class Transit {

public Transit() {
}

@Column(name = "id")
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@NotEmpty
private String sourceAddress;
@NotEmpty
private String destinationAddress;
private double price;
private DateTime date;
private Long distance;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSourceAddress() {
    return sourceAddress;
}

public void setSourceAddress(String sourceAddress) {
    this.sourceAddress = sourceAddress;
}

public String getDestinationAddress() {
    return destinationAddress;
}

public void setDestinationAddress(String destinationAddress) {
    this.destinationAddress = destinationAddress;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public DateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(DateTime date) {
    this.date = date;
}


public Long getDistance() {
    return distance;
}

public void setDistance(Long distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
}}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface TransitRepository extends JpaRepository<Transit, Long> {
List<Transit> findAllByStartDateGreaterThanEqualAndEndDateLessThanEqual(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/transit")
public class TransitController {
private TransitService transitService;

@Autowired
public void setTransitService(TransitService transitService) {
    this.transitService = transitService;
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void addTransit(@RequestBody Transit transit){
    transitService.calculateDistance(transit);
    transitService.addTransit(transit);
    System.out.println(transit);
}

@RequestMapping(path = "reports/daily", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void getDailyReport(){}

}
```

And service class:

```
@Service
public class TransitService {

private TransitRepository transitRepository;
public static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxx";

@Autowired
public void setTransitRepository(TransitRepository transitRepository) {
    this.transitRepository = transitRepository;
}

public void addTransit(Transit transit) {
    transitRepository.save(transit);
}

public void calculateDistance(Transit transit) {

    GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder().apiKey(API_KEY).build();
    DistanceMatrixApiRequest request = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(geoApiContext);

    DistanceMatrix result = request.origins(transit.getSourceAddress())
            .destinations(transit.getDestinationAddress())
            .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
            .units(Unit.METRIC)
            .awaitIgnoreError();

    long distance = result.rows[0].elements[0].distance.inMeters;
    transit.setDistance(distance);

}

public void countDaily(List<Transit> transitList){

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the annotaion `@RequestParam` on the parameters you need to add to your method. The name in the annotaion is optional and defaults to the parameter name.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "reports/daily", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void getDailyReport(@RequestParam("start_date") String startDate, @RequestParam String end_date){}

}
```

Adding the fields to your `Transit` class would not work as the GET-Request has no request body and the parameters are not in the body anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Are you sure that in this case date should be String type or I have to change it?

Comment: Depending on the date format an auto-convertion by Spring could also work but you should test this. Dates are difficult to auto convert because of the multiple formatting patterns.

Comment: But in this case when I have to compare that date is between two dates I think that i can't use Spring right? I tried with Date type but this one is including minutes, I want to do it with pattern: yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@RequestParam` annotation in your controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "reports/daily", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void getDailyReport(@RequestParam("start_date") String startDate, @RequestParam("end_date") String endDate){

     // Create a method in service class, that takes startDate and endDate as parameters.

     // And inside that method, you can write a SQL query to find the distance & price for the given date parameters

}
```

Comment: Hi I added new method in repository class (question edited) and there is problem, becouse I there is no property startDate found for type Transit so I can't turn on my app... Am I doing right?

Comment: Hey, I did what You say but when I make get request it doesn't work, can You check my app at github: https://github.com/Dezet-IT/TransitApp ?

Comment: In your code, you wrote `startDate` and `endDate ` instead of `start_date` and `end_date ` in `@RequestParam`. Please check it.